# Why is my Parse Sign Up Code Not Getting Ran?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery, buddy.com

In my main view controller, when a button is pressed I run the following code:

```
if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in
        // Create the log in view controller
        CustomSignUp *logInViewController = [[CustomSignUp alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Create the sign up view controller
        self.signUpViewController = [[TheActualSignUp alloc] init];
        [self.signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
        self.signUpViewController.fields = (PFSignUpFieldsUsernameAndPassword
                                            | PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton
                                            | PFSignUpFieldsEmail
                                            | PFSignUpFieldsAdditional
                                            | PFSignUpFieldsDismissButton);
        [self.signUpViewController.signUpView.additionalField setPlaceholder:@"First & Last Name"];

        [logInViewController setSignUpController:self.signUpViewController];
        logInViewController.facebookPermissions = @[ @"email", @"public_profile", @"user_friends" ];
        logInViewController.fields = (PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword
                                      | PFLogInFieldsFacebook
                                      | PFLogInFieldsTwitter
                                      | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton
                                      | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton
                                      | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten);

        // Present the log in view controller

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:logInViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

The view controller for a login screen shows up, and I can successfully log in an already created user.  However, when I try to sign up someone, I run into issues.  The sign up window appears fine, and I type in all the codes, but when I click the button to send the info in to sign it up, nothing happens.  Here is the code (in the same view controller).  Would greatly appreciate any help on this.  Am using Parse on Buddy.com.  None of the NSLogs are getting called when signing up.

```
- (BOOL)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController shouldBeginLogInWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password {
    // Check if both fields are completed
    if (username && password && username.length != 0 && password.length != 0) {
        return YES; // Begin login process
    }

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information"
                                message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!"
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    return NO; // Interrupt login process
}
// Sent to the delegate when a PFUser is logged in.
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {

    PFUser *me = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSLog(@"Regular Login");

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didFailToLogInWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to log in...%@", error);
}

// Sent to the delegate when the log in screen is dismissed.
- (void)logInViewControllerDidCancelLogIn:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController shouldBeginSignUp:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"Signup");
    BOOL informationComplete = YES;
    // loop through all of the submitted data
    for (id key in info) {
        NSString *field = [info objectForKey:key];
        if (!field || field.length == 0 || ![signUpController.signUpView.additionalField.text containsString:@" "] ) { // check completion
            informationComplete = NO;
            break;
        }


    }

    // Display an alert if a field wasn't completed
    if (!informationComplete) {

        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information"
                                    message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information, including first & last name!"
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }

    return informationComplete;

}
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user {
    NSLog(@"Signed them up");
    [user saveEventually];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // Dismiss the PFSignUpViewController


}

// Sent to the delegate when the sign up attempt fails.
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didFailToSignUpWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to sign up...");
}

// Sent to the delegate when the sign up screen is dismissed.
- (void)signUpViewControllerDidCancelSignUp:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController {
    NSLog(@"User dismissed the signUpViewController");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code, it's not immediately obvious as to what the problem is. If you ping Parse on Buddy's customer support at support@buddy.com, we can help.